# Prove that there is an increasing sequence $\{a_n\}$ of points in $A$ such that $\lim a_n = \sup A$.

Tags: real-analysis

Since $\sup A$ is a limit point of $A$, then there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $A$ such that $a_n \rightarrow \sup A$. How can we show that $a_n$ can be increasing?

Comment: Start with an easy example: can you find an increasing sequence of elements in $(0,1)$ that increases to $1$?

Comment: Yes, 1 - 1/n. But how can I generalize this?

Comment: Try using the definition of the supremum

Comment: What if I said: Let $\{x_n\}$ be the sequence contained in A which converges to supA. Now let $a_n$ = inf{$x_k : k \geq n$}. Then $a_n$ is an increasing sequence. One can show that $a_n$ converges. $a_n <$ supA. Therefore, $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence which converges to supA.

Comment: In general, the supremum might not be a limit point (depending on your definitions).  Are you assuming that the supremum is a limit point or that the sequence is nondecreasing?

Comment: I am assuming the supremum is a limit point.

Comment: @Johnver is that given as a part of the question?

Comment: No, but the supremum has to be a limit point of A. Any open ball around the supremum must contain at least one point in A not equal to the supremum.

Comment: It is not true that a neighborhood of the supremum must contain a point in A not equal to the supremum.  For example, the supremum of $[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ is 2, but 2 is not a limit point.

Answer (score 2):

Construct your sequence as follows:

Let $a=\sup A$ and let $a_0$ be any point of the set other than $a$.

Let $\delta_1=|a-a_0|/2$.  Since $a$ is the supremum of $A$, there is some $a_1$ such that $a_1\not=a$ and $|a-a_1|<\delta_1$.  You can show that $a_1>a_0$.

Continue iteratively and you will have constructed such a sequence.

(This is assuming that $\sup A$ is actually a limit point.  If it is not a limit point, but a point of the set, you can only find a nondecreasing sequence).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that they mean non-strictly increasing, as in the case of $A = \{0\}$.

**Hint:** let $\alpha = \sup A$.  For each $n \in \Bbb N$, there must be an element $a \in A$ such that $\max\{\alpha - 1/n,a_{n-1}\} < a \leq \alpha$.  Define this to be your $a_n$.

Comment: Note that this is not enough to guarantee that the sequence is increasing.  However a subsequence of this construction will be increasing.  Also, the inequality $a\leq\alpha$ should be strict to guarantee increasing.

Comment: @MichaelBurr fixed it